# Load x more results?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following snippet which i use to load xml via jQuery from a xml file:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myxml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("seperator").each(function () {
                $("body").append($(this).attr("MyAttr"));
        });
    }
});
```

The xml file can contain hundreds of results. So instead of just showing them all at once, i would like to add a "Load 20 more.." button to the page, that will.. load 20 more results. So when the page initialy loads, it shows the first 20 results, click the button and it loads and appends 20 more from the xml etc.

How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** Just a demo code represents an example that will help you to find your right way.

```
var items = [];

// creating some demo items
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    items.push($('<div>Index ' + i + '</div>'));
}

var alreadyAdded = 0,
    // keep index of last added item
    total = items.length; // total # of items
// function that will add element


function add() {
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        $('#container').append(items[alreadyAdded]); // adding element
        alreadyAdded++; // increasing index to keep record of last one added
        if (alreadyAdded % 20 == 0) { // checking that if 20 items added
            return false;
        }
        if (alreadyAdded == total - 1) $('.load').hide(); // hide load button when all items added
    });
}

$('.load').on('click', function() {
    add(); // call on load more click
});

add(); // initial call for add first 20 items​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9MKaQ/1/)**